# dbcontext not saving nor catching exeption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext, savechanges

I am using a dbContextwhich is described as the following

```
 public class DbContext: System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }   
    public DbSet<Sesison> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

And in my login action for some reason after checking with the database that the user is correct i am not able to use another entity of the context to save into the database, whats happens is that i won't get the data saved into the database and it will actually stop executing code after the dc.SaveChanges() but i dont get an exeption on my catch, so what my browser is expiriencing is a 500 internal server error.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        using (DbContext dc = new DbContext())
        {
            var v = dc.UserAccounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == model.UserName);
            if (v != null)
            {
                if (GetSHA1(model.Password) == v.Password)
                {
                    Guid sessionGuid =Guid.NewGuid();
                    var session = dc.Sessions.Add(new Sesison() { SessionID = sessionGuid,StartDateTime=DateTime.UtcNow,UserID = v.UserID,ExpireDateTime=DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4)});
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IsLogin"] = true;
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"] = sessionGuid;
                    try
                    {
                        dc.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                    {
                        Exception raise = dbEx;
                        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {
                            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                                // raise a new exception nesting
                                // the current instance as InnerException
                                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                            }
                        }
                        throw raise;
                    }
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        Item1 = "true"

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        Item1 = "false",
                        Item2 = "The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again."
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    Item1 ="false",
                    Item2 = "The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again."
                });
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What does the 500 internal server error show, because if that's what's happening I would say that it's not a `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException` being thrown when you try and save.

Comment: i have no idea, since i just get it on consle since its runned from jquery

Comment: seems like you are right, i made some changes to the jquery to output the erorr The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Session_Users". The conflict occurred in database "FuelSensorDev", table "dbo.Users", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The call to SaveChanges is throwing an exception of a type other than DbEntityValidationException

A quick look at the DbContext SaveChanges call shows that it might throw the following types of exceptions. If you don't want to handle each then you probably want to add a generic Exception handling to find the problem.

```
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:
    //     An error occurred sending updates to the database.
    //
    //   T:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException:
    //     A database command did not affect the expected number of rows. This usually indicates
    //     an optimistic concurrency violation; that is, a row has been changed in the database
    //     since it was queried.
    //
    //   T:System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException:
    //     The save was aborted because validation of entity property values failed.
    //
    //   T:System.NotSupportedException:
    //     An attempt was made to use unsupported behavior such as executing multiple asynchronous
    //     commands concurrently on the same context instance.
    //
    //   T:System.ObjectDisposedException:
    //     The context or connection have been disposed.
    //
    //   T:System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     Some error occurred attempting to process entities in the context either before
    //     or after sending commands to the database.
```